# getElementById() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, getelementbyid

The following code is somewhere between my head tags:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/homepage.js"></script>
```

Somewhere in the body:

```
    <input type="text" id="registreervoornaam" name="registreervoornaam" placeholder="Voornaam">
```

In my homepage.js:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var regname = document.getElementById("registreervoornaam");
    regname.focus = function() {
        alert("bla");
    };
};
```

Somehow I do not get an alert when focussing on the input field. Any idea's on what this might be? I added the function in the onload because otherwise regname will become null as the javascript file is parsed before the body.

Comment: direct element event handlers are always `.onfoo`, never just `.foo`.

Comment: I pity the .foo who makes this mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i would do to solve this:

1. See if the value returned by getElementById is `null`. If it is, it means that your element doesn't exist in the page. If that is the case, you may want to put all of your scripts at the end of the markup file, so that when the scripts are loaded, the whole DOM has already been loaded.
2. If you are already importing jQuery, why not use it? :D I would just do:

   ```
   $("#registreervoornaam").focus(function() {
        //do stuff here that you want to be triggered on focus
   });
   ```
3. i just realised that there is no "focus" in plain js :/ I would use onfocus instead. Here are more details about it >> [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp)

Good luck! :D

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to set up the event handler that way, the property name is "onfocus", not "focus".

```
regname.onfocus = function() {
    alert("bla");
};
```

Answer (score -2):

And if you have jQuery on your page you could write :

```
$(function(){
$("#registreervoornaam").onfocus= function() {
    alert("bla");
};
```

});

Comment: This is invalid code, '.onfocus= function(){ ' should be '.focus(function () {'